# Validate stored data against a form in django

Tags: python, django, validation

Obviously when you save data through a form you can run validation through it's clean method, but then if you wanted to re-validate that data every time you view it can you just run the form's clean method again?

I was thinking the view would go along the lines of;

```
def detail(request, person_id=None):
    """
    Renders an individual person
    @param employer_id: The id of employer to view
    @param request: HttpRequest
    @return: HttpResponse
    """
    person = get_object_or_404(People, pk=person_id)

    validation_form = AddForm(instance=person)
    is_valid = validate_person(validation_form)

    return render_to_response(
        'person/detail.html',
        {
            'is_valid':     is_valid,
        },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But what would be the 'proper' way of doing `validate_person()`?

**Solution**

I've discovered an object has a `.__dict__` method, so with that the solution I have is;

```
form = AddForm(person.__dict__)
is_valid, errors = validate_person(form)
```

Then my helper function can return is the form is the valid, and errors if there are any;

```
def validate_person(form):
    """
    Validate that the data stored for the person passes validation.

    @param person: Person object
    @param form: Form
    @return: Boolean
    """
    if form.is_valid():
        return True, None
    else:
        return False, form.errors
```

Now I just need to figure out some list comprehension on the template to display the errors!

Comment: [you can have a look at the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#using-validation-in-practice) to see how the validators work for each Field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You could do that.Pass the data from person object to PersonForm. See the example.

```
form = PersonForm({'firstname':person.firstname,.....})    
is_valid = form.is_valid()
```

Comment: Spot on - that's what I need. Just a shame you have to specify the dict & django magic can't just figure out what you want from the object.

Comment: I found a better way, instead of passing a dict, you can `.__dict__` an object to do the same thing! I knew it had to be possible! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think a combination of what you already have and what Srinivas suggested would work:

```
def detail(request, person_id=None):
    """
    Renders an individual person
    @param employer_id: The id of employer to view
    @param request: HttpRequest
    @return: HttpResponse
    """
    person = get_object_or_404(People, pk=person_id)

    validation_form = AddForm(instance=person)

    return render_to_response(
        'person/detail.html',
        {
            'is_valid':     validation_form.is_valid(),
        },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: My helper function `validate_person()` did a `form.is_valid()` and returned false with the passed in instance of `person`, but it works by specifying the dict :(